# XSLT transform resulting in only the page heading h1::Documents being printed in html, if XML prefix is used

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I'm new to transforming xml to html using xslt. I'm not

This is resulting in only the page heading h1::Documents being printed in html. The same template xslt and C# code will work on straight forward xml, but *it doesn't seem to work on this doc with the prefix dme:*

#### XML:

```
<dme:WfMessage Version="1.1" xmlns:dme="dme">         
  <dme:WfTransport>
    <dme:Connection Mode="individual" Type="synch"/>
  </dme:WfTransport>
  <dme:WfMessageHeader> 
    <dme:Response/>
  </dme:WfMessageHeader>
  <dme:WfMessageBody>
    <dme:FetchDocumentList.Response>
      <dme:Document>
        <dme:ID>136</dme:ID>
        <dme:DOC_CLASS>MEDIA</dme:DOC_CLASS>
        <dme:DOC_NUMBER>3166</dme:DOC_NUMBER>
        <dme:REVISION>3</dme:REVISION>
        <dme:DIS_MEDIA_CAT>PICTURE</dme:DIS_MEDIA_CAT>
        <dme:IL_POC>Craig</dme:IL_POC>
        <dme:IL_TITLE>White Monkey</dme:IL_TITLE>
        <dme:DIS_FILETYPE>JPEG</dme:DIS_FILETYPE>
        <dme:IL_POSTDATE>1045238867710</dme:IL_POSTDATE>
        <dme:IL_DOCID>P33333S</dme:IL_DOCID>
        <dme:IL_KEYWORD>Monkey</dme:IL_KEYWORD>
        <dme:IL_COUNTRY/>
        <dme:IL_SUBCODE_IFC/>
        <dme:IL_SECUR_NONUS_CLASSIF>TS</dme:IL_SECUR_NONUS_CLASSIF>
        <dme:IL_SECUR_RELTO>AUS/CAN/NZ/UK/US</dme:IL_SECUR_RELTO>
        <dme:HITLIST_VIEW/>
        <dme:Security>
          <CONTENT_VIEW>1</CONTENT_VIEW>
          <CATALOG_VIEW>1</CATALOG_VIEW>
          <HISTORY_VIEW>1</HISTORY_VIEW>
          <RESERVED_VIEW>1</RESERVED_VIEW>
          <CONTENT_EDIT>1</CONTENT_EDIT>
          <CATALOG_EDIT>1</CATALOG_EDIT>
          <ANNOTATE>1</ANNOTATE>
          <SECURITY_EDIT>1</SECURITY_EDIT>
          <ANNOTATE_VIEW>1</ANNOTATE_VIEW>
        </dme:Security>
      </dme:Document>
      <dme:Document>
        <dme:ID>137</dme:ID>
        <dme:DOC_CLASS>MEDIA</dme:DOC_CLASS>
        <dme:DOC_NUMBER>3235</dme:DOC_NUMBER>
        <dme:REVISION>1</dme:REVISION>
        <dme:DIS_MEDIA_CAT>PICTURE</dme:DIS_MEDIA_CAT>
        <dme:IL_POC>Brian Peterson</dme:IL_POC>
        <dme:IL_TITLE>SUNSET IN CALIFORNIA</dme:IL_TITLE>
        <dme:DIS_FILETYPE>JPEG</dme:DIS_FILETYPE>
        <dme:IL_POSTDATE>1045491585360</dme:IL_POSTDATE>
        <dme:IL_DOCID>908934NI3990</dme:IL_DOCID>
        <dme:IL_KEYWORD>SAMPLE SUNSET</dme:IL_KEYWORD>
        <dme:IL_COUNTRY/>
        <dme:IL_SUBCODE_IFC/>
        <dme:IL_SECUR_NONUS_CLASSIF>TS</dme:IL_SECUR_NONUS_CLASSIF>
        <dme:IL_SECUR_RELTO>UK</dme:IL_SECUR_RELTO>
        <dme:HITLIST_VIEW/>
        <dme:Security>
          <CONTENT_VIEW>1</CONTENT_VIEW>
          <CATALOG_VIEW>1</CATALOG_VIEW>
          <HISTORY_VIEW>1</HISTORY_VIEW>
          <RESERVED_VIEW>1</RESERVED_VIEW>
          <CONTENT_EDIT>1</CONTENT_EDIT>
          <CATALOG_EDIT>1</CATALOG_EDIT>
          <ANNOTATE>1</ANNOTATE>
          <SECURITY_EDIT>1</SECURITY_EDIT>
          <ANNOTATE_VIEW>1</ANNOTATE_VIEW>
        </dme:Security>
      </dme:Document>
      <dme:Document>
        <dme:ID>138</dme:ID>
        <dme:DOC_CLASS>MEDIA</dme:DOC_CLASS>
        <dme:DOC_NUMBER>3236</dme:DOC_NUMBER>
        <dme:REVISION>1</dme:REVISION>
        <dme:DIS_MEDIA_CAT>PICTURE</dme:DIS_MEDIA_CAT>
        <dme:IL_POC>Brian Peterson</dme:IL_POC>
        <dme:IL_TITLE>Winter scene</dme:IL_TITLE>
        <dme:DIS_FILETYPE>JPEG</dme:DIS_FILETYPE>
        <dme:IL_POSTDATE>1045491652920</dme:IL_POSTDATE>
        <dme:IL_DOCID>E4323452345234</dme:IL_DOCID>
        <dme:IL_KEYWORD>WINTER</dme:IL_KEYWORD>
        <dme:IL_COUNTRY/>
        <dme:IL_SUBCODE_IFC/>
        <dme:IL_SECUR_NONUS_CLASSIF>TS</dme:IL_SECUR_NONUS_CLASSIF>
        <dme:IL_SECUR_RELTO>UK</dme:IL_SECUR_RELTO>
        <dme:HITLIST_VIEW/>
        <dme:Security>
          <CONTENT_VIEW>1</CONTENT_VIEW>
          <CATALOG_VIEW>1</CATALOG_VIEW>
          <HISTORY_VIEW>1</HISTORY_VIEW>
          <RESERVED_VIEW>1</RESERVED_VIEW>
          <CONTENT_EDIT>1</CONTENT_EDIT>
          <CATALOG_EDIT>1</CATALOG_EDIT>
          <ANNOTATE>1</ANNOTATE>
          <SECURITY_EDIT>1</SECURITY_EDIT>
          <ANNOTATE_VIEW>1</ANNOTATE_VIEW>
        </dme:Security>
      </dme:Document>
      <dme:FetchDocumentFrom>0</dme:FetchDocumentFrom>
      <dme:FetchDocumentCount>3</dme:FetchDocumentCount>
      <dme:FetchDocumentFetchSize>0</dme:FetchDocumentFetchSize>
      <dme:FetchDocumentTotalCount>3</dme:FetchDocumentTotalCount>
      <dme:COMPLETION>0</dme:COMPLETION>
    </dme:FetchDocumentList.Response>
  </dme:WfMessageBody>
</dme:WfMessage>
```

#### XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:dme="dme"
exclude-result-prefixes="dme">
  <!--<xsl:param name="transformDateTime"/>   Can use this once rest of code is working-->
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Documents</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1><xsl:attribute name="style"> color:red</xsl:attribute>Documents</h1>

        <!--<p>Transform DateTime <xsl:value-of select="$transformDateTime"/></p>-->

        <xsl:apply-templates></xsl:apply-templates>   <!--<this line of code makes all of the info under documents print in HTML>-->
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="FetchDocumentList.Response">
    <ol>
      <xsl:attribute name="style">color:blue</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Document"/>
    </ol>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Document">
    <li>
      <h1>
        <xsl:value-of select="IL_TITLE"/>
      </h1>
      <p>
        Document Id:  <xsl:value-of select="ID"/>
      </p>
      <p>
        Media Type:  <xsl:value-of select="DIS_MEDIA_CAT"/>
      </p>
      <p>
        Artist:  <xsl:value-of select="IL_POC"/>
      </p>
      <p>
        Document Number:  <xsl:value-of select="DOC_NUMBER"/>
      </p>    
    </li>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

#### C# Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Xsl;
using System.Xml;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace TechPractice
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                XslCompiledTransform myTransform = new XslCompiledTransform();

                myTransform.Load(@"F:\Practice\\Transform.xslt");

                XsltArgumentList xsltArgList = new XsltArgumentList();

                //string transformDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString();
                //xsltArgList.AddParam("transformDateTime", "", transformDateTime);

                XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(@"F:\\Practice\\NewDoc.html");

                myTransform.Transform(@"F:\\Practice\\SourceDoc.xml", xmlWriter);

                Process.Start(@"F:\\Practice\\NewDoc.html");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems clear to me that you need to make your code aware of the XML namespace `dme`, but I'm not quite sure how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your templates aren't matching your elements due to the prefix- in other words, you're matching `Document`, not `dme:Document`; they're not the same element name as far as XSLT's concerned.

Realistically, I think the only way is to have your template match `*[local-name()='Document']`, instead of just `Document`.

If you were using XSLT2 or later, there's the `xpath-default-namespace="dme"` attribute you could set on your stylesheet, but that's not an option in C#, unless you're using a third-party library like Saxon. Your best bet is probably to either amend your XSLT to ignore the namespacing using the `local-name` trick, or pre-process your XML to remove the namespace first.

EDIT: Just noticed you've also got `<xsl:apply-templates select="Document"/>` in there too, that'll also need to be updated to `select="*[local-name()='Document']"`.

Comment: This *[local-name()=' '] works   :)  Thanks so much, I really appreciate it :)

Comment: NP: Just to clarify btw- the `*` means 'match any element', and the `[]` is a filter that limits that to only those matching the expression.

Answer (score -1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Xsl;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
   class Program
   {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           try
           {
               XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
               doc.Load(@"c:\users\prasath\documents\visualio
    2010\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\book.xml");
               XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
               xslt.Load(@"c:\users\prasath\documents\visualio
    2010\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\book.xsl");
               XmlTextWriter wrt = new XmlTextWriter(Console.Out); //
               //should probably be a StreamWriter in real code
               wrt.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
               xslt.Transform(doc, wrt);
               Console.ReadKey();
           }
       }
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

The way may Differ Try this to improve functionality

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Xsl; 

namespace XSLTransform{
    class myclass
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XslTransform xslTran; 
            xslTran = new XslTransform();
            xslTran.Load("XSL PATH"); 
            xslTran.Transform("XML PATH"); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, changing the C# code is not resolving the problem. I think it may have something to do with the xml file and how its structured. I feel like i'm missing a using or something similar, but I just can't figure it out.  Thanks again for trying though.